# I'm a sculptor & need a 3d photosphere of a human head for reference, is that possible?

Tags: 3d, apps

Google searches are not yielding the right results and I don't know what to search on. I'd like to create a "photosphere" that is directed inward (capturing all possible angles of a person's head) instead of outward, which is the normal way and shows the room/ world around the photographer. I'd like the final movable image to work like a photosphere so I can drag the image around to reference different views of the person's head on my tablet (either Android or iPad) as I'm sculpting.

Is this possible? Is there a name for it I can use when searching for an app that would help me create these? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that what you want is to create a 3D model from a series of photographs of your subjects head.  The process of doing this is technically a form of [photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry)

This can be done reasonably cheaply and simply now days via taking a series of photos at different angles of your model (with a single hand held camera), and then feeding the individual photos into software that then creates the model from those images.

The final model then can be rotated and zoomed as desired in various 3d model editors.

[Here](https://i.materialise.com/blog/en/how-to-make-a-3d-printed-object-from-a-photo-in-5-easy-steps/) is a random blog that discusses the process.  I found this blog by googling "create 3d models from photos" (note I am not affiliated with this blog - and there are a zillion other websites that show similar techniques)

The one caveat is that because you are building a 3D model, you'll have to know something about the 3D software itself and be able to do things like clean up artifacts that can arise because the model is stitched together from non-contiguous photos.

Another item you may want to google is "360 photography turntables" (and related subjects).  These are used to rotate an object while you take photos from a fixed camera location.  I once saw a documentary of a photographer going to comic-cons and using such a setup to take 360 degree photos of people in costume.

And finally, if you have $$$ to spare you can investigate "multi-camera rigs"  that surround your subject with cameras and take all the required photos at a single instant.  This will help with ensuring you have correctly aligned and lit images, but you'll still have to go through the same stitching process as with a single camera.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter! This is so much closer to what I was hoping for - whew. :) I'm definitely not in the market for a multi-camera rig (wow! $$$ indeed). Creating a 3d model from photos can't be *too* much worse than printing out 60 still images and arranging them in a usable way around my workspace. <g> Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for a ["bullet time camera array"](http://mitchmartinez.com/bullettime/) also called a ["timeslice camera array"](https://www.newworlddesigns.co.uk/production-bullet-time-rigs/camera-array/).

It allows you to take a picture of a person or object from many angles at the same time. This can then be processed in such a way that you can "move around" the object and view it from different angles.

Comment: Thanks. I'm amazed no one has come up with an easier way to do this for a still object. I figured I'd be able to sit someone on a slowly spinning stool and take a series of photos that could be stitched together, ha. Guess technology isn't quite there yet. :)

Comment: @Michelle ask and you shall receive .. lol

Comment: The modern movie equivalent for capturing an entire human for FX work is about 240 cameras rigged into a scaffold forming an almost complete sphere. It's not, of course, dealing with action of any sort, it just makes one big 3D still. I've been inside one many times but I've never operated one, so I'm not sure how it all maps.

Comment: @Tetsujin what are those camera rigs called? I tried searching for them, but could not find the right term.

Comment: I’ve been trying to think of what they’re called. We just call it’ going to get scanned’ which doesn’t really give much of a clue;)

Comment: @Michelle I have seen the term "multi-camera rigs" used for the physical setup and the process is technically "photogrammetry"